# Dependency, reference - vocabulary around nodes in dependencies graph

Tags: graph, dependencies, uml

In software engineering we often need to describe relation of dependency. I.e. dependencies in between modules/libraries/projects/packages or symbols in the code (e.g. class Foo uses class Bar therefore Foo depends on Bar). The often symbolic notation is an arrow (derived I believe from UML) that makes pretty clear what depends on what, e.g. Foo --> Bar indicates that Foo depends on Bar.

When module Foo depends on module Bar, we simply call that Bar is a dependency of Foo.
The problem I often struggle is how to call the element on the left side of Foo --> Bar relation.

Is there a simple term to describe what is Foo for Bar?

Answer (score 4):

In the UML the roles in a dependency are called *supplier* and *client*. The client is dependent on the supplier. So, Foo would be a client of Bar, and Bar the supplier for Foo.

From [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) § 7.7.1 page 37 :

> A Dependency signifies a supplier/client relationship between model elements where the modification of a supplier may
>   impact the client model elements.

Comment: I taken the liberty to edit your answer to including material from the norm, if you disagrea do not hesitate to revert my edit.